# pm-utils hook-script failed on pkill signal (Beagle-Bone)

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack

I want my application be notified (signaled) if my BBB Board is
going to suspend or resume.

So I added a hook-script in

```
#! /bin/sh
#/etc/pm/sleep.d/15_myapp
 case "$1" in
       suspend)
            pkill -SIGUSR1 myapp>/dev/null 2>&1
            ;;
       resume)
            pkill -SIGALRM myapp >/dev/null 2>&1
            ;;
       *)
            ;;
 esac 
 exit $?
```

So far so good, every time I try to suspend the board

```
 ajava@debainBBB:~# pm-suspend
```

I get immediately the Message on the same Consule with a description of
my pkill signal:

```
User defined signal 1
```

the suspend-process is then broken.

So I checked the /var/log/pm-suspend.log

```
        Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:

    /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.
    Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
    Linux jetMaster 3.12.19-rt30+ #29 PREEMPT RT Wed Jun 25 15:02:55 CEST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
    Module                  Size  Used by
    rfcomm                 35643  0
    bluetooth             238755  3 rfcomm
    usb_f_acm               7016  2
    u_serial               11485  1 usb_f_acm
    usb_f_mass_storage     45500  2
    libcomposite           42382  12 usb_f_acm,usb_f_mass_storage
    musb_dsps               7540  0
    at25                    4594  0
    lm75                    4802  0
    rtc_ds1307              8243  0
    musb_am335x             1680  0
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:        506180      66696     439484          0       7104      32204
    -/+ buffers/cache:      27388     478792
    Swap:            0          0          0

    /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.
    Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:

    /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.
    Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/15_myapp suspend suspend:
```

As you can see there is no success after calling my script. 
But I already have checked the exit-status of my hook-script its 0 (i .e success)

Have any of you folks any idea what's going on here?
Why am I getting the signal description as out put of pm-suspend?

Thanks.

--- UPDATE --------------------------------------------------

The Problem seems to be the standard behavior of the Signal defined here
[signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)
Apparently every Signal ending with terminating the process causes 
the pm-suspend to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to be the standard behavior of the Signal defined here signal(7) Apparently every Signal ending with terminating the process causes the pm-suspend to fail.